# MS Access VBA: What does OpenRecordSet return?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

A very simple question to those who have worked with VBA for Access before.

```
Set S = CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet("select COLUMN from TABLE")
```

Is S now an array of all the values that are in COLUMN?
If not, how can I otherwise use a `For Each` loop for those values that are in S ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Did you look at the documentation?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966(v=office.15).aspx)

```
Do While Not S.EOF

    value = S!COLUMN

    S.MoveNext

Loop
```

Comment: I am sorry, I read some few documentations, but I really did not find the one you posted. Maybe I googled wrong.
Can you please just tell me, if I now want to manipulate with current `value` , i just write what I want to do with it, inside this loop?
And then it will take another row in that Column, and will manipulate with it, the same? (as `For Each`would) ?

Comment: You need to .MoveNext on the recordset!

Comment: Sorry, that's what you get for rushing - I've updated my answer.

Comment: @AndroidNFC what is it you need to do with the values?

Comment: Thanks Guys for the help!
@jmdon I would like to take that string and use MID() on it, to get a certain value of that string and then compare it to another if it matches.

Answer (score 0):

CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet returns an Object of Type "Recordset"

And this object has several methods, e.g EOF, MoveNext, Fields which you can use to iterate over the rows.